# Whats wrong with my SQL syntax generated by python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I tried to generate some code to insert excel data into mysql database, but so far I have some trouble with it. It says ProgrammingError at /
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= ('Barcelona - Sants','Good',2.1331,41.3788,'NA','NA','NA','0h','Good',84,'NA',' at line 1")

can anyone help me?

```
'''
sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO {} (' .format(db_sheet)
for i in range(0,sheet.ncols):
    sql_insert += 'item{},'.format(i)
sql_insert = sql_insert[:-1]
sql_insert += ') '

excel_data = list()
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    row_content = []
    for j in range(0,sheet.ncols):
        ctype = sheet.cell(r,j).ctype # 判断单元格数据类型
        cell = sheet.cell(r,j).value

        if ctype==1: #如果是字符串，
            cell = cell

        elif ctype==2 and cell % 1==0: #如果是整形
            cell = int(cell)

        elif ctype==3: # 如果是日期型
            dt = xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(cell, book.datemode)
            cell = dt.strftime('%Y/%M/%D %H:%M:%S')

        elif ctype==4:
            cell = True if cell==1 else False

        row_content.append(cell)
    values = tuple(row_content)
    excel_data.append(row_content)
    cursor.execute(sql_insert, values)

'''

print(sql_insert%values)  
# ====>outputs
INSERT INTO air_quality_Nov2017 (item0,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10,item11,item12,item13,item14) values = (Barcelona - Observ Fabra,Good,2.1239,41.4183,22h,Good,64,22h,Good,21,22h,Good,12,30/11/2018 23:00,1543615502)

while excuting in mysql via command lines, it gives the same error info.
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Get rid of the = after values

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...);`